# Convert input field to text with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert `<input type="text" value="1" class="simpleCart_input">` to plain text.

Like I need it to be something like

```
<span class="simpleCart_input">1</span>
```

But how?

Comment: @Kooilnc how could I achieve it then?

Comment: I answered your initial (and initially only) question. For an answer to the later added 'how' question you can pick one. I think the `replaceWith` answer looks promising ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `replaceWith`.

```
$('.simpleCart_input').replaceWith(function(){
   return '<span class='+this.className+'>'+this.value+'</span>'
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fsVRe/

or:

```
$('.simpleCart_input').replaceWith(function(){
    return $('<span/>', {
              'class': this.className,
               text: this.value
           })
})
```

Comment: It's nice and fancy, but maybe too fancy for me :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly this should do it:

```
var a = $('.simpleCart_input').html();
alert(a);
```

Based on your comment you want this:

```
var a = $('.simpleCart_input').val();
$('.simpleCart').text(a);
```

(For the code to do it's purpose you need a span with the class simpleCart.)

**Final suggestion:**

Just to add the code for converting. This will remove the input field and insert a span with the desired value.

```
$('.simpleCart_input').replaceWith(
    return '<span class='+this.className+'>'+this.value+'</span>'
);
```

Comment: This simply alerts it. I need it to be displayed as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gvRjn/

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

Hope it fits your cause `:)`

P.S. - this is using http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable plugin.

**Code**

```
$('.editable-element').editable({
    width: 250,
    indicator: 'Saving...'
});


​
```

Answer (score 2):

***HTML***

```
<span>
    <input type="text" class="simpleCart_input">
</span>​
```

***jQuery***

```
$('.simpleCart_input').blur(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    $(this).parent().attr('class', $(this).attr('class')).html(val);
});​
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JEDWv/1/)***

#### Another

```
$('.simpleCart_input').blur(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    if( val ) 
    {
      $(this).wrap($('<span/>', {
        'class': $(this).attr('class'),
         html: val
      })).remove();
    }
});​
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JEDWv/2/)***

Comment: Bruv, some medical issues and stuff needed heaps of rest! all good now :) I was usually refreshing the page from my ipad heh `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit glad to know everything is good now... thanks again.

Comment: Works, but not the solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
$("input.simpleCart_input").replaceWith(function () {
  return '<span class="'+this.className+'">'+this.value+'</span>';
});​
```

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/n8z8w/)***

Comment: Why not +1 to you as well `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean get the value of the input field? If so:

var val = $('.simpleCart_input').val();
alert(val);

Comment: Well, something like this, but I don't want it like this. I need `<input type="text" value="1" class="simpleCart_input">` change to `<span class="simpleCart_input">1</span>`

Comment: You can hide the input using 

`$('.simpleCart_input').hide();`

Then append a span element to your body, or a DIV you create

`$('body').append("<span class='simpleCart_input'>1</span>");`

I would do it like this:

`<div class="simpleCart">`
`<input type="text" value="1" class="simpleCart_input" />`
`</div>`

Then 

`$('.simpleCart_input').hide();` // (or .remove() depending on if you will ever show the input again or not.)
`$('.simpleCart').append("<span class='simpleCart_input'>1</span>");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = $('.simpleCart_input');
input.replaceWith(
    $('<span>').text(  // Uses text() to avoid breakage if the value contains HTML special characters.
        input.val()
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very simple:

First you need to identify the input so we will add it an id:

```
 <input id="my-input" type="text" value="Lorem ipsum" />
```

Then we can replace the input with text doing something like:

```
 var input = $('#my-input'),          // cache input
     value = input.attr('value'),  // read input value
     span  = $('<span></span>);    // create a span element     

 span.text(value); // Place the value inside the span     
 input.after(span); // Place the span after the input     
 input.remove(); // Remove the input since this was our mission
```

This should do the job :)